# Propagation rules of touch/click events

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-edittext

I've tried some variations of some code I'm trying to implement and I'm a bit confused as to why things are happening the way they are.  I'm hoping someone can explain it to me.

I have a layout file with various elements including a ListView.  The layout file for the ListView item looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#ffffff">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="#ffffff">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/topicGoalsTextView"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/chevron"
                />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I set the ListView's OnItemClickListener() to listen for touch events to go to the next screen.  However, when I click outside the EditText view, the onItemClick() method is not being called.

I considered the fact that the EditText within the ListView item was causing the ListView events to be caught and not propagated.  I took out the EditText from the above layout file and the onItemClick() method was called, as expected.

This would lead me to believe that the sibling TextViews of the EditText view could receive click events.  This was correct.  That worked.  It also led me to believe that the ancestor LinearLayouts of the EditText would NOT receive click events if I clicked outside the EditText view.  This is not the case.  Both the parent LinearLayout holding the EditText AND the grandparent LinearLayout that holds the entire ListView item both received click events whenever I clicked outside the EditText view.  Clicking inside the EditText view did not, however, propagate to its ancestors.  That is what I had hoped.

So if the ancestor widgets are able to receive click events outside the EditText, why then, is the parent ListView not receiving the event to trigger the onItemClick() method?  Why does the EditText prevent events from propagating back to the ListView?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal behavior for the editText to become selected in a listview.  In many cases people want to enter text into a listview row.

You could set a listener for the `EditText` such as `EditText.setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListner)` or `EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener)` and then in your listener you can move to the next screen.

Another option would be to just use a drawable resource which looks like a `EditText` rather than a real `EditText`.